# How to get cluster point in a scatter plot?

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

[image]

I have a scatter plot....How to plot centroid in it??

stat_summary(fun = mean)??? or??

I tried the code below but... i need a cluster point?

```
plot(Period_1_AB, Period_2_AB, pch = 0 , cex = .8)

points(Period_1_BA, Period_2_BA, pch = 2, cex = .8)

abline(0,1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do this by simply plotting the mean using `points()`:

Data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(100),
                 y = runif(100))
```

Plot - here, I plotted the centroid of the points in red.

```
plot(df, pch = 19)
points(mean(df$x), mean(df$y), pch = 19, col = "red")
```

[image]

Edit: per your comment requesting `ggplot2::geom_point`, one way would be:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(lapply(df[], mean)),  
             aes(x = x, y = y), col="red")
```

[image]